# R is trimming off my reference output

Tags: r

I hope this question has not already been solved but I couldn't find any answers.

Below R will give me an output of "Time difference of 6.783333 hours" which is exactly what I want to see.

```
Start = "2013-04-19 16:42"
End =  "2013-04-19 23:29"


dtm <- strptime(c(Start), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "CET")
dtms <- strptime(c(End), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "CET")


t_time = dtms - dtm

t_time
```

Now In my loop below it does not write the text to my column, only the numeric values.

As an example I don't know if the number 6.78333 represents hours, seconds, days, months or years.

I would like to see "Time difference of 6.783333 hours" written in the column

```
x <-1:555500
for(i in seq(along=x))

{

LookUpAccount = DateCorrection$Account[i]
LoopData =  DateCorrection[ DateCorrection$Account ==LookUpAccount , ]
FrameLoop = as.data.frame(LoopData$Account)

    if(i > 1){
    if(DateCorrection$Account[i] == DateCorrection$Account[i-1] )
    {
    s = DateCorrection$Account[i]

    DateCorrection$AcctCheck[i] = s
    dtm <- strptime(c(DateCorrection$NewDate[i]), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "CET")
    dtms <- strptime(c(DateCorrection$NewDate[i-1] ), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "CET")


    t_time = dtm - dtms

    #R is trimming off the time reference description and only leaving me a numeric number
    DateCorrection$TimeDiff[i] = t_time

    }
    }
}
```

Attached is the DataFrame

```
    'data.frame':   555500 obs. of  18 variables:
     $ Account    : chr  "5345234652" "5345234652" "5345234652" "5345234652" ...
     $ Date       : Date, format: "2013-04-18" "2013-04-18" "2013-04-18" "2013-04-18" ...
     $ ContactType: chr  "GH" "FF" "GH" "GH" ...
     $ ContactCode: chr  "226" "1309" "1309" "1306" ...
     $ EmpID      : chr  "5722  " "1883  " "9588  " "C45061  " ...
     $ Duration   : chr  "393" "2589" "690" "184" ...
     $ OBS        : chr  "19013359390" "19013360497" "19013361117" "19013361956" ...
     $ Month      : chr  "Apr" "Apr" "Apr" "Apr" ...
     $ Year       : chr  "2013" "2013" "2013" "2013" ...
     $ Freq       : int  28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 ...
     $ Mil        : chr  "PM" "PM" "PM" "PM" ...
     $ Hour       : num  14 15 16 17 22 14 15 15 16 16 ...
     $ Min        : num  45 45 22 25 1 17 38 43 10 42 ...
     $ HourMin    : chr  "1445" "1545" "1622" "1725" ...
     $ NewDate    : chr  "2013-04-18 14:45" "2013-04-18 15:45" "2013-04-18 16:22" "2013-04-18 17:25" ...
     $ TimeDiff   : chr  "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" "1" "37" "1.05" ...
     $ SecondsDiff: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ AcctCheck  : chr  "Y" "5345234652" "3423253453" "34787644763" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- capture.output(print.difftime(dtms-dtm))
#[1] "Time difference of 6.783333 hours"
```

It would probably be preferable to specify the unit (instead of having it automatically selected) and only store the numeric value:

```
difftime(dtms, dtm, units = "hours")
#Time difference of 6.783333 hours
difftime(dtms, dtm, units = "days")
#Time difference of 0.2826389 days
```

Answer (score 1):

The display mode of values is controlled by the value’s class.

The `class(t_time)` is `difftime`; displaying such a value thus calls the function `print.difftime`. `class(DateCorrection$TimeDiff)`, on the other hand, is `numeric`. However, you can simply reassign the column’s class:

```
class(DateCorrection$TimeDiff) <- 'difftime'
```

However, notice that if you display the *data frame*, the time difference will still be shown in an abbreviated format. To get it in long format, print just the `TimeDiff` column.

Answer (score 0):

You can coerce you variable to difftime using `as.difftime`.

> as.difftime(tim, format = "%X", units = "auto")

Here and example:

```
(dd <- data.frame(TimeDiff = 1))
  TimeDiff
1        1
## you coerce it now 
dd$TimeDiff <- as.difftime(dd$TimeDiff,units='hours')
dd
  TimeDiff
1  1 hours
```